# Ansible include roles based on OS version

Tags: ansible

I have below files `csi.yaml` file, it include the roles beased on the OS version. this work but if I run it on CentOS 8, its giving `skipping:` message all the task in RHEL7-CIS tasks.

```
roles:
   - { role: RHEL7-CIS, when: ansible_distribution == "CentOS" and ansible_distribution_major_version == '7' }
   - { role: RHEL8-CIS, when: ansible_distribution == "CentOS" and ansible_distribution_major_version == '8' }
```

try to include the role based on OS version this but its giving error also.

```
 gather_facts: True
roles:
 - "RHEL{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}-CIS"
```

> ERROR! 'ansible_distribution_major_version' is undefined

Is there an alternate way of including the role based on OS version?

Thanks
SR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just suppress output from skipped tasks using custom callback. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39189835/4948949) for details.